# htaccess 301 redirect not working

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm trying to add a simple 301 rule to the .htaccess file of a codeigniter site.

```
redirect 301 /newsletter http://sub.domain.com/newsletters/may2010
```

When I visit http://sub.domain.com/newsletter the redirect goes to

```
http://sub.domain.com/newsletters/may2010/?/newsletter
```

I'm not sure where the ?/newsletter is coming from. Full .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /    

    redirect 301 /newsletter http://sub.domain.com/newsletters/may2010

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>



<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

#####################################################
# CONFIGURE media caching
#
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
<FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
Header unset Last-Modified
Header set Expires "Fri, 21 Dec 2012 00:00:00 GMT"
Header set Cache-Control "public, no-transform"
</FilesMatch>
#
#####################################################

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh, this is Apache pulling a sneaky order-of-processing trick on you. As it turns out, the fact that you put your `Rewrite` command at the top of the file doesn't mean that it's what's actually executed first. What happens instead is that `mod_rewrite` is run first, followed by `mod_alias` (which is responsible for handling your `Rewrite`).

This results in the following transformation, per `mod_rewrite`:

```
newsletter --> index.php?/newsletter
```

`mod_rewrite` happily sets the query string to `?/newsletter`, but because you don't have the `PT` flag specified, does *not* passthrough the rewritten URL `index.php` to `mod_alias`. Therefore, `mod_alias` still sees the `/newsleter` path, redirects it to `http://sub.domain.com/newsletters/may2010`, and appends the (now changed) query string `?/newsletter` to the end to seal the deal. Fun stuff, right?

Anyway, a quick-fix for this scenario would be to ignore requests for just `newsletter`:

```
#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !newsletter$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```